# Module extension, to not repeat myself

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my first Angular project.

Basically, I have two modules which have too much in common, module A, and module B which just have extended features of module A. So for clarity sake, module A is the parent, B the child.

What I'm trying to do :

```
var modA = angular.module('modA', [...]);
// module A controllers, directives, services and stuff

var modB = angular.module('modB', ['modA']);
// some other directives and services depending on module A 

modA.controller('main', function(scope){
   // Here it should execute modA controller logic

   // @override 
   var someFunctionInModA = function(){
        parent.someFunctionInModA(); // also not sure how this is done
        // other stuff
    }

});
```

What I found so far :

```
angular.extend(this, $controller('modA', {$scope: $scope}));
```

Similar things exists for services, some uses $injector, I'm missing some clear (and simple) ressources about the subject.

Comment: `angular.decorator` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this direction, never had heard of it. Will try this out.